# How to plot this in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

This is what I'm trying to do: I have the following diagram (called the phase space plot):

[Phase space diagram http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/attachment.php?attachmentid=185627&d=1354917185](http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/attachment.php?attachmentid=185627&d=1354917185)

The paper which i'm following says :

> The phase space plots of the signals were divided
> into a grid of 20x20 squares and the number of points c(i,j)
> within a square was computed to form the phase space
> density matrix c.

I tried the following code in order to do the above :

```
    %%matrix(1,:) Is the first row and all columns. This row has the actual signal of  
    %interest and corresponds to the x axis of the above graph.
    and is the x axis of the above graph.
    %matrix(2,:) Is the second row and all columns and comprises of the y axis of the  
    above graph.

    for i=1:180:size(matrix,2)
        for j=1: 180 : size(matrix,2)
            if isnan(matrix(1,i))
            else
                c(1,i)=matrix(1,i);
            end
    
            if isnan(matrix(2,i))
            else
                c(2,i)=matrix(2,j);
            end
        end
    end
    
    figure,plot(c)
```

The output is :

[image: grid]

I am meant to get something like this :

[paper http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/attachment.php?attachmentid=185629&d=1354918102](http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/attachment.php?attachmentid=185629&d=1354918102)

The LHS is the phase space diagrams and the RHS corresponds to the respective plots which I am trying to get to.

Help plz!!!

Would be very grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: It isn't very clear here what you are wanting to do...

Comment: If you look on the left hand side of the second image that I posted, you will see four diagrams. The four diagrams on the right hand side correspond to the ones on the lhs.

I am trying to do what the paper is asking me to do(the highlighted section). Thanks.

Comment: @Hasnain, Yeah, I read this a few times and I'm still lost. Can you try clarifying exactly where your difficulty lies?

Comment: Jerad,Iam trying to implement a scientific paper in MATLAB. The first part involves creating a 'phase space plot' (the first image in my post) which I have done. 

The next part involves dividing the space space plot into a grid of 20 X 20 squares & calculate the number of points within a square. This is what I'm trying to do

If you look at the second image, fig 4.a for e.g That is what I'm trying to achieve. 

Thanks!!

Comment: @Hasnain, the code you provided doesn't do any plotting, so without knowing what you've tried and why it's not working, it's hard to offer suggestions.

Comment: Apologies, I have edited my post and shown what I've plotted. I am aware that what iam after is a 3d plot (fig4.a) but wasnt quite sure how to verify what ive done is right. Thanks.

Comment: @Hasnain for the first plot did you try `plot(c')` instead of `plot(c)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use function [`hist3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html).

For example

```
x = randn(100, 2);
hist3(x, [20 20]);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I did look into that function and my methodology is as follows :

I ran the algo I posted initially in my first post and got 'c'. This was a 2X3600 matrix. So i casted this into a 3600 X 2 dimension matrix. Then i used the hist3 function which you kindly pointed me towards and resulted into the following :

![img] (http://s12.postimage.org/b7aojn1l9/Untitled.jpg)

Comment: However it doesnt seem to correspond to 
![Phase space](http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/attachment.php?attachmentid=185627&d=1354917185) 

Just like
![paper](http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/attachment.php?attachmentid=185629&d=1354918102) 
where the top left graph on the left hand side corresponds to fig 4.a 

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but your phase-space plot (the first figure you have posted in the question) isn't the same as fig 3.a either.

Comment: I agree. Perhaps that is because the datasets are different. Either way, I think the phase space plot should correspond to density plot ( the new plot i created with the hist3 function) as shown in the paper. What do you think? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, from what you have uploaded in the above comments, it seems to me that the `hist3` plot you created corresponds to your phase space plot (most of the points are approximately in the interval [-0.3, -0.1] in the x-axis and around zero in the y-axis). It seems to me that the density of the "circular regions" is comparatively too small to be seen in the `hist3` plot.

Comment: Yes! Your a star mate! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you probably want some kind of 2d histogram? 
Look here for help: http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/01/22/advanced-making-a-2d-or-3d-histogram-to-visualize-data-density/

You can also look at the file exchange for some 2D hist functions(my first search gave me this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1487)

EDIT: @3lectrologos has the right function